# How to use bootstrap table class .table-hover and .table-striped on a table

Tags: html, css

when I use .table-hover and .table-striped together, hover mood doesn't work on the table.I use **Bootstrap v2.3.1**

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">First</th>
                        <th scope="col">Last</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td>Mark</td>
                        <td>Otto</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">2</th>
                        <td>Jacob</td>
                        <td>Thornton</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
      </table>
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you've connected bootstrap properly and haven't overwritten classes ?
https://codepen.io/helping083/pen/mdEbLvE?editors=1010
I've copied your code and it works.

Comment: @Олег Войтинський I use Bootstrap v2.3.1 and I haven't overwritten any class.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine you can check it over here in snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">4</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">5</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">6</th>
          <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank You...